# Set project fingerprint

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

Trying to create Android application that uses authentication with Firebase.

```
            Intent signInIntent = AuthUI.getInstance()
                    .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                    .setAvailableProviders(providers)
                    //.setIsSmartLockEnabled(false)
                    .build();
            signInLauncher.launch(signInIntent);
```

Evrything goes fine if I disable smartlock. In case I use it I get `Error when saving credential`:

> com.firebase.ui.auth.FirebaseUiException: Error when saving credential.
> at com.firebase.ui.auth.viewmodel.smartlock.SmartLockHandler.lambda$saveCredentials$0$com-firebase-ui-auth-viewmodel-smartlock-SmartLockHandler(SmartLockHandler.java:97)
> at com.firebase.ui.auth.viewmodel.smartlock.SmartLockHandler$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onComplete(Unknown Source:2)
> at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzi.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.2:1)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
> Caused by: com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 16: Cannot find an eligible account.
> at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.ApiExceptionUtil.fromStatus(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.0.1:3)
> at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zap.onComplete(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.0.1:4)
> at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.BasePendingResult.zab(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.0.1:7)
> at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.BasePendingResult.setResult(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.0.1:6)
> at com.google.android.gms.internal.auth-api.zbm.setResult(com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth@@20.3.0:1)
> at com.google.android.gms.internal.auth-api.zbk.zbc(com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth@@20.3.0:1)
> at com.google.android.gms.internal.auth-api.zbr.zba(com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth@@20.3.0:7)
> at com.google.android.gms.internal.auth-api.zbb.onTransact(com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth@@20.3.0:3)
> at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1154)
> at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1123)

Looks it is related to fingerprint. I have created fingerprint in browser, in Firebase project console. But where I should put this fingerprint in my project?

Answer (score 1):

1. go to firebase console
2. project settings
3. scroll down to Android app, if not exist crerate one
4. add the SHA-1 fingerprint

Then download the google-service.json and update your project with the new google service file.

Comment: I did all that except fact that I have added two fingerprints - sha1 and sha256. I have updated my project with `google-service.json`. But have `saving credential` problem